# Why can't I assign and save this model summary? (in Lavaan, an R package)

Tags: r, object, data-modeling, r-lavaan

I estimate a latent variable model in `lavaan` in `R`, such as

```
library(lavaan)
HS.model <- ' visual  =~ x1 + x2 + x3
              textual =~ x4 + x5 + x6
              speed   =~ x7 + x8 + x9 '

fit <- lavaan(HS.model, data=HolzingerSwineford1939,
              auto.var=TRUE, auto.fix.first=TRUE,
              auto.cov.lv.x=TRUE)
```

I would like to assign the model summary to an object and `save` it.

```
fit.sum <- summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)
```

However,

```
> fit.sum
NULL
```

Furthermore it is not possible to call the fit indices (e.g. `RMSEA`) from the model summary (e.g. `summary(fit, fit.measures=TRUE)$RMSEA` or alike).

1. Why can't I save this model summary?
2. How can I save the model summary? The background is that I have a
       large model and `summary()` actually needs a lot of computing time
       to give output. It seems some statistics are computed when calling
       `summary()`.
3. How can I extract the fit indices from `summary()` or where else can
   I access them in `fit`?

Comment: Because the summary method doesn't return anything, it just prints information. If you read about the `lavaan` class object you'll see a list of lots of methods for extract specific pieces of information about the model.

Comment: Okay --  I also see now one may use `inspect(fit, "fitMeasures")` with `$rmsea` to extract the fit measures